# Give access of script only to specific id in the url

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript file and want to load it only to some specific ids to load in head.
The domain when user is logged in is `www.domain.com?id=122`
And the script url is `www.domain.com/script.js`
And I put the script with parameter in head of home page if user is logged in `www.domain.com/script.js?id=122`
And I get the id from the current url by split and some JavaScript stuff. Now the problem is what to add in the script file to make the script load only for some specific ids

Comment: "The domain when user is logged in is www.domain.com?id=122". This instantly sets alarm bells ringing for me. Could I change that URL to www.domain.com?id=123 (or whatever) and be logged in as another user? Obviously you can't have that, and need things like session cookies to establish user identity - but why then do you need the user ID in the URL?

Comment: It's a big website and the id is different from user to user. But the id in script url which I put in head changes to be as the user id. So I am asking what to do in the script to make it load for specific users. For example user ids 123, 132 and 546

Comment: You've missed the point I'm making - which is separate from your question, I admit, but is a fundamental thing that would mean you need a major rethink of your architecture, if you're getting it wrong. What is to stop any random person on your site simply changing the URL to have a different numeric ID and getting access to all the features that other user should have?

Comment: No the url not opening if the user didn't login with email and password

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can check the URL parameter, and create a `script` tag from code only if you are satisfied:

```
if(location.search === "?id=122") {
  let s = document.createElement("script");
  s.src = "script.js";
  document.head.append(s);
}
```

However it's not something what could be used for security purposes for example.

Comment: But the url of script will be available for all users

Comment: @Aaab You can't really hide anything in HTML+JS. A completely different thing you can look into is generating content on the server side, like with PHP. A PHP script can check whatever conditions it wants to and return different content for different parameters.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But there is any other technology other than PHP